# Rails find countries by region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Country gem https://github.com/hexorx/countries, and need help with with

```
list = Country.find_all_countries_by_region('Americas')
```

I have the following method

```
def get_Americas_countries
        @job_countries = Refinery::Jobs::Job.select("DISTINCT(country)").all
       # ::ISO3166::Country.find_all_countries_by_region('Americas')
end
```

in my application controller where I get the list of all countries, but I want to get only the countries which is from Americas region. I can't figure it out how can I do this. any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_Americas_countries
  list = Country.find_all_countries_by_region('Americas').map(&:alpha2)
  @job_countries = Refinery::Jobs::Job.select("DISTINCT(country)").where(:country => list)
end
```

[EDIT]

list is now an array of country codes

Comment: Thanks Slicepan, I get 'undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass', when use list, any idea?

Comment: Is name is the name of the country? I now get an empty array. I have two jobs listed in American region. but now I ge --- []? On job model I get the name of country like this
  "def country_name
        ::ISO3166::Country[country]
      end"

Comment: Here is post query: 
Refinery::Jobs::Job Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT(country) FROM "refinery_jobs" WHERE "refinery_jobs"."country" IN ('Antigua and Barbuda', 'Anguilla', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'Argentina', 'Aruba', 'Barbados', 'Saint Barthélemy', 'Bermuda', 'Bolivia', 'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba', 'Brazil', 'Bahamas', 'Belize', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Colombia','Virgin Islands, U.S.)

Comment: ok, so what is the value of the country column for the two jobs listed in the american region? does it match any of those country names?

Comment: mx, I posted one Job in maxico and I use the alpha2 code to store country names. I trim down the country list, because the editor was not able to post that long list. but maxico is in the list. Let me try Europe.

Comment: Does uppercase and lowercase matters? all the counties are stored in country column in lower case like "gb", but the qurey search useses "GB". that's why I get empty list.

Comment: Depends on the collation of the table in the DB, you can map the list array to lowercase by doing `list.map!(&:downcase)`

Comment: Bam, this is working now. thank you so much, really appreciate your time :-)